# glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin not working in Angular2

Tags: javascript, css, .net, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="display:inline-block;float:right; margin-right:20px;">               
    <a style="font-size:2rem !important;" class="btn btn-ok margin-top-10" > 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin"   (click)="GetAmbiguityAnalysisResult()" >
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I wanted to use spinner for refreshing data.
I have used above code.

Data is getting refreshed. But icon is not spinning.

Answer (score 0):

try using this 
**{{span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat normal-right-spinner">}}**.
i think this will work,but if u wish to use spinners, u can also try
Bootstrap spinners like this.
**{{Spinning:}}
{{i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"}}**